# How to change pictures in asp.net to Combo box Selected Index Change

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, combobox, web, selectedindexchanged

I just want to change my panel background image according to the selected index in ComboBox in asp.net web site. But the images not loading. This is my code in .aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<div id="divx" style="height: 250px">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="242px">
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

And this is code behind..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   }
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        Panel1.BackImageUrl="C:\\Users\\Laksh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\Pic\\Capture.JPG";
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        Panel1.BackImageUrl="C:\\Users\\Laksh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\Pic\\erroe.JPG";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you thought about using Server.MapPath("../Pic/Capture.JPG"); to get the file path name of the image?

Comment: Yeah i tried sir.. but it gives an exception...
`'C:/Users/Laksh/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/WebSite2/Pic/Capture.JPG' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.`

Comment: Server.MapPath maps a virtual path to a physical location - so this will result in an exception!! see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is **not possible to set an aboslute path**, referring to a location on your local disk! this results in a code like ...

```
<!-- This imageURL won't work!! -->
<div id="Panel1" style="height:250px;background-image:url(c:%09emp%0demo.jpg);">       
</div>
```

Use a **relative path** instead!

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.BackImageUrl = "~/pic/error.jpg";
}
```

If you are not sure what to do, you can always assign a backgroundImage to a panel using the *design View* of your aspx page. Just *select your panel*, go to *Properties*, Click property *BackImageUrl* and *select an image* within your project. VS will than add a perfectly working path to your image!

Comment: This should work but I don't think the postback approach is ideal. The UX is terrible. Consider registering a client (JS) on-change event to avoid the need for a post back every time the user switches between items.

Comment: Of course this would be better, but as autoPostBack was in the original question, I didn't change that detail. But feel free to post an example, so I / we could learn of it! thx in advance

Comment: But this method also not working.. sir... it dint give any exception.. but not loading image at all..

Comment: I assume that within your project there is an pic folder, and within that folder there is a error.jpg image. Pls update your question if i was false?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Pilgerstorfer Franz, use a relative path i.e. ~/xyz... and do a server.mappath. Usually the web server doesn't have rights to the local machine outside of the server directory heirarchy so mapping directly isn't a great idea.

You might also try using jQuery to do the change, you might try something like the below. You'll need to have it pull your values from your ddl, but you can pass that into your function, or have it reference the ddl's value field maybe...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
            function doIt()
            {   
                $('#divTryMe').css('background-image','url("test.jpg")');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divTryMe" onclick="doIt()">stuff</div>
    </body>
</html>
```